# Display entire IP Address range knowing Minimum and Maximum values?

Tags: c#, .net

I'd like to display the entire range of ip addresses given the min and max values of the ip range.

So, if a user inputs: "192.168.1.1-192.168.2.255"  I'd like to then display the individual addresses to the user. I was wondering what the fastest way to calculate all the IPs and display them in a list.

I am using the [TakeIo.NetworkAddress](http://www.nuget.org/packages/TakeIo.NetworkAddress/) library to calculate the range, but I need a way to display all the addresses between the min and max values.

Comment: Not sure what the question is...it's trivial to generate a sequence of 4-set integers that describe the range between one IP address and another; each "digit" (between each dot) is like a digit in an integer, except the range is 0-255 instead of 0-9.  That being said, the feature doesn't sound very useful to me.  Is it that hard to enter in an IP address?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far to do this yourself?

Comment: @sa_ddam213, I agree this is a duplicate.

Comment: @Ken, honestly, I have not tried to write any code. I wanted the communities input first.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/172661). SO isn't a "Here's my requirement. Please write my code." site. :)

Comment: @KirkWoll, regardless of it being useful or not, it is a requirement for a project. I also realize that it seems trivial to you, however, I was asking what the fastest way is to evaluate the range to display all the IPs in that range. If you look at my example input, you will notice the 3rd octets in each range are 1 and 2. So, we would have to compare that those are not equal and make sure we span those ranges. sa-ddam213 helped by pointing out some code I can leverage.

Comment: @Ken, I didn't ask anyone to write my code I asked for a suggestion as to the fastest way to perform this task. Perhaps I should have posted this in a different forum.

Comment: So you're optimizing before you have anything that you've even written and benchmarked as performing poorly? ;-) There can't be a fastest until there's something to be faster than in the first place.